# Attempting to calculate someone's age using the year they were born and the present year

Tags: r

I created the dataset in R and I have been struggling to find a way to get RStudio to come back with a solution

I tried using:

```
dat1$age <-dat1$currentyear - dat1$born
```

But I keep getting:

```
Error in dat1$currentyear - dat1$born : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

I just need to find out how old someone would be in 2021, given their birth year. I was trying to get their current age to appear in the dataframe which along with name, born, and friends, but not have any other dataset showing. [work example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKMvt.png)

Comment: 1. First you should not add data as images. It is easier to help if you provide data in a [reproducible format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269) . 2. From the screenshot `born` is a character variable so you need to change it to integer/numeric. Try `dat1$age <- dat1$currentyear - as.integer(dat1$born)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `born` is registered as a character variable. Convert it to numeric and you should be good to go.

```
dat1$born = as.numeric(dat1$born)
```

Now compute the age difference. If this answer worked, you may close this question.